# Choosing from multiple credit cards, radio button or dropdown?

Tags: e-commerce, dropdown, radio-buttons, checkout

On a checkout page we offer the ability to store credit card information. Once a customer has stored their card(s) we need to offer them the ability to choose which card they would like or add a new card.

Which would be a better interface:

1) A radio list that shows each card that has been added, with the last option: "New Credit Card". The "new credit card" option would reveal the CC inputs.

-- OR --

2) A drop-down defaulted to the most recently used card that when clicked reveals all other cards as well as a "New Credit Card" options. The "new credit card" option would reveal the CC inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with option #2 as drop downs work well for selection inputs that can have an arbitrary number of options.  A radio list that contains a fixed number of choices works well in certain situations, but what if a customer has 10+ credit cards?  This would start to cause layout and UX issues, whereas a drop down just works.

Edit: I would note that several online retailers use the second approach, however, Amazon notably does not; they show all available credit cards (and associated info) to the user in a grid.  I would still argue that in general the drop down is going to be easier to manage from a design perspective, but there are other answers here that present good points.

Comment: Apparently in America a person will have an average of anything between [1.96](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/credit-card-industry-facts-personal-debt-statistics-1276.php) to [3.5](http://www.postconsumers.com/education/how-many-credit-cards-does-the-average-american-have/) credit cards.

Comment: I don't think the design should be driven by the 0.01% of users who both have 10 credit cards and register all 10 with the webservice.

Comment: Of course, the 10 cards is just an example and I agree with your sentiment, but the problem potentially manifests with just 3 or more depending on the design of the interface.  Drop downs are designed to handle arbitrary selection situations like this one.

Answer (score 3):

There could be an Option 3 with both
Radio for default usage is better visual than a default in the combobox.
For user with only one card you could disable/remove the second option.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHxK1U.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I remember a basic rule saying: "If you have enough room, use radios, not dropdown". Dropdown is a control where it is easier to mistake and harder to notice that.

Comment: I like that rule.  I'm inclined to agree. They're much easier to scan.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 would be better for any user who has entered in more than one credit card. Presenting a single visible set of card details at a time removes any chance of users becoming anxious at the thought of paying on the wrong card. Amazon's basket checkout page is a good example of this taken to an even further extreme - this selects the user's default card and provides a link to a separate page to make and confirm any changes.

With radio buttons they're far more likely to spend additional time checking and re-checking their selection as the other sets of card details will carry equal visible weight on the page.

Answer (score 1):

*"Dear technical support,
today I tried to make a purchase on your site, but my credit card got lost last week, and I couldn't find an option to add a new card on your site.
Please help. With Kind Regards, Charles Philip Arthur George."*

Since the frequency people select an alternative card (to their main/default one) is low, showing each card can be considered as 'noise'. Hiding less needed options in a drop-down seems like a good idea in these circumstances.

**But**, I really dislike the thought of hiding the 'add new' option in the drop-down - expect many users not figuring this one out (instantly at least). A user asking "how do I add a new card" will not have a clear answer on screen. The affordability of a drop-down is to allow selection between multiple items, not to facilitate further actions. So I suggest you keep the drop-down, but place the 'add new' outside it.

Answer (score 1):

3) Showing the last card along with a link/button that offers the users to switch to a different card or to add a new one. If switching to a non-default card is indeed a rare scenario like @Izhaki suggested, this could be the best way, with the most effective default behavior.

4) Using a set of radio buttons + New for up to 3 cards and switching to a dropdown beyond that. This solves the problem of using a dropdown for 1-2 values, which is very bad practice, but also takes care of the numerous cards scenario.